# What going wrong with my js inarray()

Tags: jquery, arrays

```
var element = "";
var aval_qty = "";
var all_qtys = [];
var chk = "";
$.each(data.response.tot_avl, function (a,b){
    aval_qty = '.qty'+b.id_itm;
    $(aval_qty).each(function(i, obj) {
        $(this).children().eq(0).val(b.qtys);
    });
    all_qtys.push(parseInt(b.qtys));
});
if($.inArray(parseInt(0),all_qtys)){
    $('.btn-primary').attr('disabled',true);
}else{  
    $('.btn-primary').attr('disabled',false); 
}
```

let me say array `(all_qtys)` has values of `0,10,20`.

array has 0 value in it trying to disable submit button..is some thing wrong with array push

Ex; array has item quantity's if any item quantity is zero need not to allow user to submit

Comment: can you start with formatting your code?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i am totally new to this site so week on formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($.inArray(parseInt(0),all_qtys)!== 0){ 
$('.btn-primary').attr('disabled',false); 
}else{  
    $('.btn-primary').attr('disabled',true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the object is in the array, inArray will return return the index of the element in the array, not a boolean indicating if the item exists in the array, but since 0 is false in Javascript, the following will output: "is NOT in array".

```
var myarray = [];
myarray.push("test");

if(jQuery.inArray("test", myarray)) {
    console.log("is in array");
} else {
    console.log("is NOT in array");
}
```

Comment: thanks for your time.Is it possible to convert array values as string and check??